# Is it possible to sync my Gmail contacts with my Google Apps account?

Tags: data-synchronization, gmail, google-apps, carddav

I have had a Gmail account for as many years as they've been available, but recently I've moved to use my own domain name with Google Apps. So now I have a Gmail account *and* a Google Apps account.

They are *nearly identical* but they are not identical. For example, Google still seems to offer some features to Gmail users before Google Apps users. Until recently, Google Voice was not available for Google Apps, and so I created my Google Voice number through my Gmail account.

The problem now is that I have a Google Apps account where I use email, and a Gmail account where I use Google Voice. Why is this a problem?

**Contacts.**

I need/want up to date phone numbers on my Gmail account to help with Google Voice, but I need/want up to date email address information on my Google Apps account.

So I need/want to sync *two* Gmail/Google Apps accounts with my Mac and with my iPhone and iPad.

I have been searching for ways to sync these without much success.

I have tried:

- [Plaxo](http://www.plaxo.com) (seemed like it *should* work, but didn't work well. Also $60/year).
- [Spanning Sync](http://blog.spanningsync.com/2012/07/end-of-the-line-for-spanning-sync.html) (worked well until Apple broke it [see link])
- Futzing around with the **Contacts.app** sync on Mac OS X to try to get it to sync two accounts (did not work at all)
- A few older "Sync your contacts to Gmail" Mac apps that I found on the web (most of which probably date back to 10.4 before OS X had this built-in).

Now that CardDAV is available, I wondered if there was any new possibility of doing this.